# send report in specific json format

Tags: python, django, json, python-2.7, django-models

views.py

```
def json(request):
    defaultnumber = []
    phoneinfo = PhoneInfo.objects.filter(user = user_id)
    for phone in phoneinfo:
        phone_no = {'id':some.id,
                     'name1':phone.name1,
                     'number1':phone.number1,
                     'name2':phone.name2,
                     'number2':phone.number2,
                   }                                }
        defaultnumber.append(phone_no)
    result = { 'phone':defaultnumber}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), mimetype="application/json")
```

I need to send the  data into json format.

Comment: Has the answer helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `model_to_dict` instead:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

def json_view(request):
    phoneinfo = PhoneInfo.objects.filter(user = user_id)
    phones = [model_to_dict(phone) for phone in phoneinfo]

    result = {'phoneinfo': phones}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), mimetype="application/json")
```

And, don't call view `json` - you are overriding `json` module name.

And, it's unclear from where `user_id` variable comes.